# SQLite update: correlated sub-query fills rows in target column with same values

Tags: sqlite, correlated-subquery

I am trying to update a column of a table with values of another table's column, depending on the values of the updated column in SQlite. Here is an example:

```
Table 1
A
1
2
3
1
3
4

Table 2
A   B
1   x
2   x
3   y
4   y

Result Table 1 after query:
A
x
x
y
x
y
y
```

From related questions, I tried the following queries:

```
update Table1 set A=(select B from Table2 where(A=Table2.A))
```

This fills col A of Table 1 with all x.

Also, another version I found here did not work, as it threw the error "no such columns: table2.B":

```
update Table1 set A=Table2.B where(A=Table2.A)
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When you write a column like `A` without a table reference, the column matches the *innermost* table.
In this case, the innermost table with a column named `A` is `Table2`, so the query has the same effect as if you had written:

```
update Table1 set A = (select B from Table2 where Table2.A = Table2.A)
```

This matches *every* row in `Table2` (and the database just takes the first one).

When you have the same column name in multiple tables, it is a good idea to always use table names:

```
update Table1 set A = (select B from Table2 where Table2.A = Table1.A)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it the way you suggest before, but the problem here is that it fills the "target" column A of table1 with all null. In dont know why, but when I only run the subquery `select B from Table2 where Table2.A=Table1.A` then the error: ´no such column: table1.A´ happens. In another thread I read that this is due to Sqlite and when I write it the way I did in the question, it works. Any idea why?

Comment: Without the outer query, there is no `Table1`. The problem is likely that there are different values in the two tables (and strings and numbers are considered different, too).

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. The Table2 columns are `CHAR` whereas Table1 is `VARHCHAR(50)`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: SQLite [does not care about column types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). What matters are the types of the values in the table.

Comment: I have worked on it with a join now. The result is the new column as states in the bottom (x,x,y,x,yy). But there is still the problem that when I want to update column A, only the first value is transferred into the whole table. The columns have the identical row number. How can I make the update so that all the values are transferred and not only the firt values in every row?

Comment: What do you mean with "with a join"?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you may not need the join there. This should work

> update Table1 set A = (select B from Table2 where Table1.A = Table2.A)